# No results with ociexecute. No error message is prompted

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have the problem, that my query won't return any results. Although no error or warnings are prompted. Although the query itself will return a result, if I directly execute it on the db:

```
//Set up Connection
$cnda = ocilogon($cnxnDabs["dbuser"],$cnxnDabs["dbpwd"],$cnxnDabs["dbname"]);
if (!$cnda) {
    $e = ocierror();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}


//Get query and the result
$query="select doc_id from k.doc_mmkt where doc_id = 19068694";
$stid = ociparse($cnda,$query);
ocidefinebyname($stid,"doc_id",&$DOCID);
ociexecute($stid);
ocifetch($stid);
```

Here is the result on the db:

```
select doc_id from k.doc_mmkt
where doc_id = 19068694

DOC_ID
19068694
```

No result via php :-(

Any advices?
Connection seems to works, since if i manipulate the e.g. dbuser, then there will pop up an warning.

Comment: I can see no error-handlig in this code. Here is a trivial example for error-handling: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/oci.txt

Answer (score 0):

> no error or warnings are prompted.

Your Oracle-related code doesn't even try to fetch error messages beyond connection errors:

```
$stid = ociparse($cnda,$query);
ocidefinebyname($stid,"doc_id",&$DOCID);
ociexecute($stid);
ocifetch($stid);
```

... so I wouldn't be surprised that your PHP environment is not configured either to display error messages. The simplest way to do so is preppending this to your source code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

And you can find usage examples on how to test for errors in the corresponding manual pages.

Note: `ocilogon` and other aliases have been deprecated for some time, it's about time you update to `oci_connect()`.

Answer (score -1):

add thi two lines instead of your `$query="select doc_id from k.doc_mmkt where doc_id = 19068694";`

$doc_id=19068694;
$query = "select doc_id from k.doc_mmkt WHERE doc_id = '" . $doc_id . "'";

Comment: Please don't suggest dumping prepared statements. Not only are they an awesome tool but SQL injection doesn't do any good to your site.

Comment: it is may be because of quotes problem..thats why i suggested like that

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your replies. I found out that the solution is to use capital letters for the name of the header:

```
//Set up Connection
$cnda = ocilogon($cnxnDabs["dbuser"],$cnxnDabs["dbpwd"],$cnxnDabs["dbname"]);
if (!$cnda) {
    $e = ocierror();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}


//Get query and the result
$query="select doc_id from k.doc_mmkt where doc_id = 19068694";
$stid = ociparse($cnda,$query);
ocidefinebyname($stid,"DOC_ID",&$DOCID);
ociexecute($stid);
ocifetch($stid);
```

Now everything goes smooth. Apparently, Oracle uses capital letters ^^.